# case clause doesn't match record type

Tags: clojure, switch-statement, record

Why doesn't the `case` clause match the record type?

```
(defrecord Rec [])
=> fargish.user.Rec

(def rec (->Rec))
=> #'fargish.user/rec

(case (type rec) Rec :YES)
=> IllegalArgumentException No matching clause: class fargish.user.Rec  fargish.user/eval25147 (form-init131856794870899934.clj:1)
```

In case you're wondering, yes, the case expression and the test-constant are equal:

```
(= (type rec) Rec)
=> true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Rec` is not a compile-time literal. Quoting from https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/case:

> All manner of constant expressions are acceptable in case, including numbers, strings, symbols, keywords, and (Clojure) composites thereof.

Alternatives:

```
(cond 
  (= (type rec) Rec) :YES)
;;=> :YES
(condp = (type rec) 
  Rec :YES)
;;=> :YES
```

Comment: Ahhhh, it does make sense after all. Many years of C got me thinking that a record is a struct (a compile-time thing). Thanks for the alternatives. I figured Clojure would have an easy way to do this that did not involve going all the way to defining a multimethod! :)

Comment: No problem. `case` is about constants. `cond` is general purpose. Until I read the docs I thought a record was a constant as well. Perhaps another answer will come up telling us exactly why a record is not a constant.

Comment: Yet another option is `(instance? Rec rec)`.